# Libspotify - what user data is available?

Tags: android, spotify, libspotify

What data is available via libspotify services in regards to user related data such as; songs played, starred tracks, following artists/genres, playlists etc for a specific user?

Also - is this data only available for an authenticated user or public users as well?

I am attempting an android application utilising libspotify, and need to wrap my head around a few things. Thanks in advance - sorry if I have missed some basic documentation, if anyone can post some links that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full API documentation for libspotify is [here](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/), and will tell you exactly what is available.

libspotify only works with an authenticated user. Songs played and following is not available, but star starred tracks and playlists are.

Comment: Thanks! Any sign of a roadmap for libspotify?